# ExtJS : paging not working and refresh button

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I use the code below. I see the grid, the content is correct but the pager section strange.

1. The button "next", "previous", ... are not enabled. There are 4 records and I ask 3 records by page, I should see "Page 1 of 2"
2. How can I manage the "refresh" button.

[image]

Thanks,

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        Ext.define('User', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
            { name: 'FirstName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'LastName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Email', type: 'string' }
        ]
        })

        var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'User',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/Home/GetUsers',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'users'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        });


        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: 'testing',
            store: userStore,
            autoScroll: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'Users',
            width:450,
            columns: [{
                text: 'First Name',
                width: 225,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'FirstName',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Last Name',
                width: 225,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'LastName',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            }],
            bbar : Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging', {
                store: userStore,
                pageSize: 3,
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
            })

        });

    });
```

Update1 :

```
{"total":2,"success":true,"data":[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"AA","LastName":"BB"},{"Id":2,"FirstName":"CC","LastName":"DD"},{},{}]}
```

I still don't see the "Page x of 2"

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/AnYeq/1/ I don't see anything wrong with the current page text.
Even with test json data without “total” property.
Controlling the refresh button is not so obvious. You can try to extend Ext.toolbar.Paging and override its private method [getPagingItems](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Paging.html#Ext-toolbar-Paging-method-getPagingItems).

Comment: AS you see the page number is empty with the same code than jsfiddle but me I use ExtJS 4.1

Comment: Before pasting this code on jsfiddle I have tested it on local web-server with Ext 4.1 with my own JSON data provider.

Comment: I don't know why two empty objects are there in json but nothing is wrong with your data and view even in IE. What browser do you use? Which doctype is defined on the page?